# Impact on system performance when database structure does not match what we specify in object relation mapping using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, heap-memory

Lately I am getting really concerned about the system performance using Hibernate. You can see in the relationship mentioned below that one main application can only have one child application. But database contains multiple child applications for the same main application.The system randomly picks one child application and this does not cause any issue that the users can notice but I am assuming that this is somehow impacting the performance in terms of heap memory in my system. Is the impact on performance is significant on such scenario?

```
class MainApplication{
@Column(name="main_app_id")
    int mainAppId;

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    List<Address> address ;
}

class SupportingApplication{
    int supportingAppId;

    //defining the relation

    @Column(name="main_app_id")
    int mainAppId

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="main_app_id", referencedColumnName="main_app_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private MainApplication mainApplication;

    String city;
    String state;   
}
```

Comment: "Randomly picks one" how? Normally this is simply a non-issue, because you don't have an owning relationship on the `MainApplication` side. Now since you're lying to Hibernate and the relationship is actually `ManyToOne`, I wouldn't expect JPA or SQL to return stable results for a join query.

Comment: That's true. I would expect hibernate to throw some error in such case but to my surprise it works fine and as you said the results are not stable.

Comment: You can tell Hibernate to log the SQL it's sending, and my guess is that it sends something like a join with either a limit 1 or no limit and then only reads one item (which might make your DB query plans a lot slower than needed).